# How to change value of tensor by index in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

i want to assign certain values from a tensor to a tensor using index as the reference, here is my idea to do the assignment, but when i run it, the softmax classifier give same values in all data, what do i miss here ?

```
for i in range(localcon1d.shape[0])  :
  for j in range(localcon1d.shape[1]) :
    for k in range(localcon1d.shape[2]) :
          tf.add(virt_image[i,coor[0],coor[1],k] , localcon1d[i,j,k])
```

Comment: The result of `tf.add` needs to be assigned to a variable. 

Also, there should be a more efficient way to add between matrixes without using a loop. (take a look into `tf.tile` and broadcasting)

Comment: @KathyWu the problem is i want to assign the value by index using my function `coor = d2xy(n,j)` to get coor[0] and coor[1]. should i use `tf.slice` ?